# Can't delete attachments from Outlook.MailItem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, add-in

My Outlook addin checks (when user click "send") if a large attachment is attached. If so it should remove it and cancel the sending and give focus back to the user.

Here's a sample of my Outlook addin code...

```
Private Sub ThisApplication_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Me.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    For i As Integer = mail.Attachments.Count To 1 Step -1
        mail.Attachments.Remove(i)
    Next
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

The active mail item still shows all the attachements. :(

How do I get Outlook to remove all the attachments (before user sends the mail) and cancel the sending?

Thanks a million!

Mojo

Comment: "_How do I get Outlook to remove all the attachments (before user sends the mail) and cancel the sending?_"  Just want to confirm, there are indeed two questions here.  The first is that you are ask why `mail.Attachments.Remove(i)` isn't working as expected.  And the second is questioning why `Cancel = True` isn't working as expected.  Correct?

Comment: Well if I set cancel = true, then the mail is not send and the users is able to make changes to the mail ... so cancel works perfectly. But the mail.Attachments.Remove(i) maybe do remove attachements in the background, but they visually is still in the mail ... I want them to be gone. :)

Comment: Try the post here for releasing things: http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=5621

Comment: @MojoDK I was just clarifying because your question wasn't clear if you were experiencing two problems or one.  I didn't want whoever was going to answer this question wasting their time debugging/speculating why the `Cancel = True` part wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Me.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    For Each a As Outlook.Attachment In mail.Attachments
        a.Delete()
    Next
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know but I have the same problem with Outlook 2010 and solved it. Neither Delete nor Remove worked for me until I added:

```
mail.Save
```